# Windows 10 massive performance drop after copying files- why?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, performance

In preparation for getting a new PC, I copied all my important files from my current PC's hard drive to a USB-connected hard drive.  I let this process run overnight, and about an hour after it finished, my PC slowed to a crawl.  Task manager showed 100% disk usage, which persisted over several power cycles, and the worst offender was "System", followed by "Antimalware Service Executable".  "Settings > Windows security > Virus and threat protection" showed "Threat service has stopped.  Restart it now." but would always fail to restart ("Unexpected error.  Sorry, we ran into a problem.  Please try again.")

After about 18 hours, I still had the same problem, despite my rudimentary troubleshooting attempts, so I decided to just reinstall windows using the built-in "Start fresh" utility.  This fixed everything.

A few days later, I decided to make another copy of all my important files, this time to a USB flash drive.  I ran it overnight, and this morning I again found that my disk usage was stuck at 100%.  After a power cycle, the virus & threat protection service is stopped again, and fails to restart.  I suspect this is not a coincidence.  What might be causing this problem?

Comment: I can (and do) copy 150 GB of machines from laptop to desktop about once a quarter. It takes about an hour and a half, throughput is steady, and there is no performance drop. Is Windows Defender finding either strange files or finding viruses? USB drive will be slower, but I can copy between USB drive and machine with no performance drop.

Comment: Should be "takes about an hour (and a half) over wireless"   15 to 20 minutes over Ethernet.

Comment: The performance drop while copying is reasonable and not really unexpected to me.  The real problem comes *after* everything is done copying.  What is the system doing?  It's just using all my disk bandwidth for... what?

Comment: It appears virus and threat protection has revived itself... and it shows no viruses or issues (apart from wanting me to set up onedrive)

Comment: Once I have finished copying, there is nothing going on (Task Manager). Try to see what Windows Defender is doing..  It could be that WD is paying extra attention to the USB source of files

Comment: Windows defender appears to be doing nothing as far as I can tell...  It's system that it using the most resources.  The problem persists even when the USB device is removed.

Comment: I am not certain. Separately I just copied some huge Outlook backup files to my desktop. Copy finished and CPU (Task Manager) rose up for 10 seconds and died down to 0. No discernable performance drop.

Comment: Windows Defender *is* system. It might be busily analyzing the backup disk. You could define it as an exemption.

Comment: I started a scan for errors on my hard disk, but cancelled it after about 20 minutes since it looked like it was going to take all day.  The disk usage died down soon after.  Maybe the problem just fixed itself given a few hours? I don't know.

Comment: Try DISM and SFC:  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Windows utility RoboCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy). Since RoboCopy uses direct disk I/O, it might be less apt to trigger the antimalware's inspection of each file as it's being copied.

You might be even better served making a disk *image*, rather than just copying specific files and folders. Tools such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) can image a disk at speeds limited only by the HDD and USB speed. On an elderly laptop, I get ~80 to 100 megabytes/second, backing up a 100 GB drive in about 15 minutes. This backs up *everything*, even system files, and you can browse the image to access *all* files, even those inaccessible while your PC is running.

Comment: I don't have the problematic laptop anymore, but I did recently use Reflect to duplicate 500GB of files on another PC with no issues.  I will accept this answer to "close" the question.